# Install sp package binaries not possible?

Tags: r, installation, r-sf

```
> install.packages("sf")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/koyeli.majumder/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependency ‘units’


  There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
      binary source needs_compilation
units  0.5-1  0.6-0             FALSE
sf     0.6-1  0.6-3              TRUE

  Binaries will be installed
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/sf_0.6-1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 39296219 bytes (37.5 MB)
downloaded 37.5 MB

package ‘sf’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\koyeli.majumder\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp6LwTYc\downloaded_packages
installing the source package ‘units’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/units_0.6-0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 912393 bytes (891 KB)
downloaded 891 KB

* installing *source* package 'units' ...
** package 'units' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

   **********************************************
   WARNING: this package has a configure script
         It probably needs manual configuration
   **********************************************


** libs
Warning: running command 'make -f "Makevars.win" -f "D:/RStudio/R-3.3.3/etc/x64/Makeconf" -f "D:/RStudio/R-3.3.3/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)' SHLIB="units.dll" WIN=64 TCLBIN=64 OBJECTS="RcppExports.o io.o udunits.o"' had status 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'units'
* removing 'C:/Users/koyeli.majumder/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/units'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"D:/RStudio/R-3.3.3/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\koyeli.majumder\Documents\R\win-library\3.3" C:\Users\KOYELI~1.MAJ\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp6LwTYc/downloaded_packages/units_0.6-0.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘units’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\koyeli.majumder\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp6LwTYc\downloaded_packages’

> library(sf)
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘units’
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘sf’
```

At first I was unable to install also but after I uninstalled rgdal package, I could install sf package. But I'm unable to load it. Results in below error.

```
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘units’
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘sf’
```

I'm unable to load package units also separately. I have a Windows 7 64 bit system.

Comment: Install package `units`.

Comment: Do you have [Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) installed? You need that to install packages that need compilation. As an alternative you can use `install.packages(..., type = "binary")` to install the slightly older binary package.

Comment: install.packages(..., type = "binary") solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Answer goes out to @Ralf Stubner.

You install `units` dependency package latest version. To compile sources into binaries you need to have installed `Rtools` package.

As an alternative you can use `install.packages` function with argument `type = "binary"` to install the older available binary package.

```
 install.packages("units", type = "binary")
```